# Avoiding Captcha

Tags: authentication

What am I doing to trigger Captcha?
Hyper-vigilance seems unnecessary -- I'm still not a robot.
How can I prevent multiple Captcha servings or even just one?  This can be most tiresome.

I search many unrelated topics at odd intervals.  More rarely I look up people for an e-mail or mailing address.  I can barely manage these operations.  My arthritic fingers apply uneven pressure and make frequent errors.

Comment: Many services use captcha, and the service is responsible for forcing you through one. Where are you even getting the capthchas?

Comment: It is unclear what you are talking about. It appears you might be wanting to talk to the support people of the service you are using.